# VS Code emmet: Diable selection of input when typing in input field?

Tags: visual-studio-code, input, emmet

How to automatically deselect the input field in emmet, VS Code ?

My problem is this every time I use emmet I need to get out of the input field otherwise what I type is always selected. And I can't use emmet twice in a row.

How to disable the selection of what I am typing ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z70yU.gif)

I want to automatically do what I did in the second console.log exemple, without needing to exit the input area of the emmet.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: That isn't emmet, it is just js snippets.  So the `console.log` snippet must be selecting the text that you type.  You could write your own snippet.

Comment: It's all the snippets for every proposition I get the same selected input.

Comment: it is not selected, is is the color of the snippet field, both executions of gif are identical, with `Esc` you can stop the snippet fields